# Org Wide Email Address being found but not being set

Tags: apex, email, org-wide-email

I have scheduled code that sends emails - I am able to see it finds the verified email address but it is not used in the sends.
Is there another step after implementing this block? My debug returns the address - the -----yes found it -------- appears when I check the logs.
Why does it not send from?
Updated snippet below

```
global void Execute(SchedulableContext ctx){
        
        
    String instanceName = [SELECT name FROM Organization LIMIT 1].name;
    String csvName = instancename+'SF  Log ';
    String subject = 'Test Mailer '+ instanceName;

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<String> toAddresses = addressMethod.getRecipientList(Label.TestSendRecipients);
  
//-------------        
    OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where address = 'address@mycompany.com'];
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    if ( owea.size() > 0 ) {
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
        system.debug('-----------yes found it ------------------ org wide email address'+owea);
    }          

        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
        email.setPlainTextBody(subject);

        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code which sends? Is it sending but with an incorrect address or no sending at all?

Comment: It sends but with my address - I have added more cde

Comment: Please double-check your code. The code here has a syntax error and won't deploy to Salesforce.

Comment: sorry I am trying not to share org specific info. Is there any thing to do to set the org wide address besides the query?

Comment: you have an errant single quote on line 3

Comment: I have fixed the errant single quote. In my org the un-redacted code runs and sends the message but NOT from the org wide address, despite debug showing it was FOUND

Comment: If the org-wide email address is not verified (or not available for the profile), then the email is sent by considering the running user's Email Settings

Comment: As listed in the question, the address is verified